# How to derive from a differential equation to its linear form $A \vec{x} = \vec b$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Take the differential equation:
$$y''+3y'+2y=0$$
To solve it we use guess an exponential solution, and from the characteristic polynomial we get:
$$y(x) = c_1 e^{-x} + c_2 e^{-2x}$$

I understand that this represents a vector space spanned by $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-2x}$.
So, there should be a representation of the problem in the form right? $A \vec{x} = \vec b$, where
$$ \vec{x} = \binom {e^{-x}}{e^{-2x}} $$

However, I don't see it.

Can it be represented like that? If yes, how? what is A ( is $ \vec{b} = \binom {0}{0} ? )$

I know that the Wronskian is used to check independence. Is this relevant in this context? Do we use it for $y,y',y''$ or for $e^{-x},e_{-2x}$?

Comment: The way you're phrasing the problem is a little strange. The vector $\vec{x}$ you have written doesn't make sense as the exponentials *are* the vectors, not the entries of some vector. The Wronskian however comes from a specific variable transformation, which I can show you in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the change of variables

$$\begin{cases}z_1 = y \\ z_2 = y'\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}z_1' = z_2\\ z_2' = -2z_1-3z_2\end{cases}$$

Represented in matrix form as

$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -2 & -3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix} $$

or

$$\vec{z}' = A\vec{z}$$

This has solution

$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix} = e^{Ax}\vec{c} = c_1 \begin{pmatrix}e^{-x} \\ -e^{-x}\end{pmatrix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2x} \\ -2e^{-2x}\end{pmatrix}$$

The Wronskian you've grown accustomed to calculating is really checking for the linear independence of these two vectors, which brings it line with previous Wronskian calculations you may have done for constant real valued vectors.

Comment: Also known as state-space representation since the state of a linear second order ODE is completely defined by its value and first derivative

Answer (score 0):

The representation is actually homogeneous type i.e. $L[y]=0$ where the linear operator $L\equiv \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+3\frac{d}{dx}+2$ is a linear combination up to second order differential operators. The solution set is a vector subspace $W$ of infinite dimensional vector space consisting of all twice differentiable functions $C^2(\mathbb R)$ so that basis for $W$ is $\{e^{-x},e^{-2x}\}$. Though the matrix form of transformation $L$ depends on the chosen basis of $C^2(\mathbb R)$ but the solution in all cases may be expressed as linear combination of  $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-2x}$.